# Java FileInputStream.read() skips bytes

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles

I am reading a binary file one byte at a time using Java's FileInputStream.read() and keeping track of the position in the file by incrementing a variable `i`. I am looking for a specific character, and for the first part of the binary file, the correct offset is returned.

However, later in the file, the offsets (as found by `i`) start decreasing from the actual offsets in the file. (For example, a character at `0x4c5` was misread to be at `0x4c3`.) As such, it appears FileInputStream.read() skips bytes. Progressively, `i` became significantly less than the actual file offset (by the end, it was 60 bytes less).

Here is some of my code.

```java
in = new FileReader(path);
int c = 0;
int i = -1;

while (c != -1) {
    i++;
    try {
        c = in.read();
        if (c == 0x47) {
            print("Found G at 0x" + Integer.toHexString(i));
        }
    } catch(IOException e) ...
```

What could be causing this? Furthermore, how can this be avoided?

Comment: Use FileInputStream for a binary file.

Comment: *"I am reading a binary file one byte at a time using Java's `FileInputStream.read()`  ..."*  - That is NOT what the code you showed us does.  And that is probably the cause of your problem (IMO).  If not, you need to show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your real problem.

Comment: Except that you are reading a text file (Reader's are text-base) so c might be two-bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are *actually* reading from a `Reader`, not an `InputStream`.  Certainly, that is what you are doing in the code you showed us!

A `Reader.read()` call will consume one **or more** bytes<sup>1</sup> and return a single `char` that is represented by those bytes.

Solution:  Don't use a `Reader` to read a binary file.  Use an `InputStream` or some subclass of `InputStream`.

---

<sup>1 - The actual behavior depends on the character encoding that `FileReader` uses.  For example, if the encoding is UTF-8, then bytes that are greater than 0x7f are treated as part of a multi-type character.  If you read arbitrary binary data as if it was UTF-8 encoded text, the result is liable to be garbage.  Certainly, I would expect the offsets to be "off".</sup>